# Check for a column name in PySpark dataframe when schema is given

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, schema

I have a schema structure as below:

```py
StructField('results', ArrayType(MapType(StringType(), StringType()), True), True), 
StructField('search_information', MapType(StringType(), StringType()), True), 
StructField('metadata', MapType(StringType(), StringType()), True), 
StructField('parameters', MapType(StringType(), StringType()), True), 
StructField('results_2', MapType(StringType(), StringType()), True),
```

And I have above columns in a file and each **file may or may not have the these columns**
and I am reading JSON file as

```py
spark.read.JSON.option(schema=schema, path=path)
```

I need to check for some column existing and make necessary transformations. I am checking for column existence as

```py
if "metadata:" in df.schema.simpleString():
```

The above is always returning "True" as I have defined schema. How to check file raw data for column existence?

Comment: Are you sure it is `spark.read.JSON.option(schmea=schema,path=path)`?

Comment: Are you looking for column existence in **data/dataframe** or **schema**?

Comment: in dataframe @AzharKhan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the file without specifying the schema:

```py
df = spark.read.option('multiline', 'true').json('file_name.json')
```

Then, if you want to check for column existance, you can use one of the following:

```py
if 'metadata' in df.columns:
```

```py
if 'metadata' in df.schema.names:
```

---

Another way is to use Python tools to check for existence of keys inside JSON:

```py
import json

j = json.loads(the_file)

if "metadata" in j:
```

Comment: Since you are not giving any schmea df.columns would give all columns in  a file. But if you have a specified schema. df. columns would give  all columns in schmea, irrespective of the file. How would you deal with this?

Comment: That's true what you say. What do you still need to deal with? I thought the python approach was sufficient? You have ways to check the existence of a column in all possible places: file, df and schema, so I don't really follow now.

Comment: yes file method is close,but I am reading file in pyspark as 
spark.read.format(json).option(path = *.json) ....  
since I am not reading file by file. it reads all columns across all json files.

Comment: Maybe you can create 2 separate dataframes? Reading with schema and without schema?